# Pandas/Python plotting data points on the chart

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot

I am looking for an alternative way of plotting data points on the chart.

Let's say I have the following dataframe:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'x':np.random.rand(10), 'y':np.random.rand(10)})
```

I would like to see on the chart the `y` values above each the data point.

Here the version of @tozCSS, which works fine.

```
ax = df.plot(kind='line',x='x',y='y')
df[['x','y','y']].apply(lambda row: ax.text(*row),axis=1)
```

The code below outputs the index as a value on the chart, is there a way to edit it so the `y` values are output:

```
ax = df.plot('x', 'y', kind='line')

for k, v in df.iterrows():
    ax.annotate(k, v)
```

Answer (score 1):

This code outputs `y` values and put them on top of each point.

```
ax = df.plot('x', 'y', kind='line')

for k, v in df.iterrows():
    ax.annotate('(%s)'%v['y'], xy=v, textcoords='data')
```